# Finding An Inverse Of K-Cycle

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

To find an inverse of k-cycle for example $(1,2,4,6,3)$ we write it from right to left $(3,6,4,2,1)$ but is it the right or left inverse? as $S_n$ is not abelian  for $n\leq 3$

Comment: In every group, the right and left inverse are the same thing. This follows from associativity and the uniqueness of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

$$(12463)(36421)=(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)=I$$
$$(36421)(12463)=(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)=I$$
These are the same and it is a right and left inverse. Note that if a group is not Abelian, it does not mean that $a\not=b\ \forall\ a,b\in S$. It just means that $a=b\ \forall\ a,b\in S$ is not true for some $a,b\in S$.

Comment: I understand, so in this case we have left inverse=right inverse, so in general if I want the left inverse or the right inverse how do I find them?

Comment: Well, since it is a group, the right inverse is the same as the left inverse.  The Symmetric Groups are well defined groups. For another algebraic structure, you could just see which value of $b$ solves $ab=e$ but does not solve $ba=e$.